# Special syntax sth.name() in the CREATE FUNCTION statement, what does it mean?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

[In this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033825/writing-a-procedure-in-postgresql-9-1) about stored procedures in `plpgsql`, the stored procedure look like `sth.name()`. I don't know what is the meaning of the prefix `sth.`

For example:

```
create or replace function something.function_name()
returns setof record as
$$
-- code
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Looking in [this book](http://chestofbooks.com/computers/databases/postgresql/practical-postgresql/index.html) in the "Part IV: Programming with PostgreSQL" I have found no mention of this type of creation declaration with a function name in two parts.

In the postgresql documentation, [at the create function section](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createfunction.html), the only similar thing is when they deal about `argtype` or `regtype` than could be written in the form: `table_name.column_name%TYPE`. But it's not related to the name of the function.

So, what is this syntax related to ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the name of a [**`schema`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-schemas.html).
In other words, a schema-qualified function name. Just like you can schema-qualify tables or views or types or even operators (you just don't have to, normally).

Also learn about the schema [**`search_path`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-client.html#GUC_SEARCH_PATH).