# Pass Parameters to trigger function to execute dynamic SQL

Tags: trigger, insert, functions, dynamic-sql, plpgsql

I have this code which was solved by Erwin:
[Execute dynamic INSERT ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE in plpgsql function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/178230/execute-dynamic-insert-on-conflict-do-update-in-plpgsql-function)

Now I want the trigger to call the trigger function `insert_data_func` with parameters (`model_cd`, `processdate`).

There are different models, that's why I'm trying to simplify things by using dynamic SQL.

*Function:*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_data_func() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$func$ 

DECLARE 
 model_cd text;
 processdate text;

BEGIN  
 model_cd := TG_ARGV[0];
 processdate := TG_ARGV[1];

 EXECUTE
  $x$INSERT INTO tb_moldsummary AS t
     SELECT $1.machine                               
          , $1.model
          , split_part(lot, '_', 1)
          , right(lot, position('_' IN lot) * -1)    
          , COUNT(lot)
          , $1.datetimestamp
     FROM   model$x$ || to_char(now(), 'YYYYMM') || '
     WHERE  lot = $1.lot
     AND    machine = $1.machine
     GROUP  BY machine, model, lot
     ON     CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT tb_summary_unique
     DO     UPDATE
     SET    machine = $1.machine                     
          , totalshots = t.totalshots + 1
          , datetimestamp = $1.datetimestamp'
 USING NEW;                                            
 RETURN NEW; 
END
$func$  
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

*Trigger:*

```
DO$$
BEGIN

EXECUTE $x$CREATE TRIGGER insert_data_trigger 
           AFTER INSERT ON modelsample$x$ || to_char(now(), 'YYYYMM') ||    
           ' FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE 
             insert_data_func' || 
            (''modelsample''' || ',' || to_char(now(), 'YYYYMM') ||  ')';
END
$$;
```

The trigger passes the model and process date parameters to the trigger function `insert_data_func()`. But I get this eror msg.:

> ERROR:  relation "model_cd201707" does not exist
>   LINE 9:          FROM   model_cd201707

How to properly use the "$x$" on the `insert_data_func()` function because I think that's the reason why the model name does not get the value from `model_cd`variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error msg says `relation "model_cd201707" does not exist`. I suppose there is no table of that name in the [`search_path`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860) then? There is a confusion of table names in your question. `modelsample...`, `model_cd...`, `model...` `tb_moldsummary`. Something is not right here ...

That aside, after assigning passed parameter values to the variables `model_cd` and `processdate` you are not using them at all (yet).

Assuming your 2 passed parameters are supposed to be used to build the table name, it might work like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_insert_data_func() 
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$func$ 
BEGIN  
   EXECUTE format(
   $x$INSERT INTO tb_moldsummary AS t
      SELECT $1.machine                               
           , $1.model
           , split_part($1.lot, '_', 1)
           , right($1.lot, position('_' IN lot) * -1)    
           , COUNT(*)  -- never null in this query
           , $1.datetimestamp
      FROM   %I
      WHERE  lot = $1.lot
      AND    machine = $1.machine
      GROUP  BY machine, model, lot
      ON     CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT tb_summary_unique  -- constraint has same name?
      DO     UPDATE
      SET    machine = $1.machine                     
           , totalshots = t.totalshots + 1
           , datetimestamp = $1.datetimestamp
   $x$, TG_ARGV[0]
   )
   USING NEW;                                            
   RETURN NEW; 
END
$func$  
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Trigger (passing a single concatenated parameter as table name):

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format(
     'CREATE TRIGGER insert_data_trigger 
      AFTER INSERT ON %1$s
      FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_insert_data_func(%1$L)'
    , 'modelsample' || to_char(now(), 'YYYYMM')
   );
END
$$;
```

Note how I use `%1$s` for the (unquoted) table name in the SQL statement and `%1$L` for the parameter (quoted as string literal). `%I` is not needed in this case for a known legal identifier. See [the manual on `format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) for details.

You may want to schema-qualify function and table names to be unambiguous. Like `public.modelsample`. More:

- [Special syntax sth.name() in the CREATE FUNCTION statement, what does it mean?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37400/special-syntax-sth-name-in-the-create-function-statement-what-does-it-mean/37402#37402)

Be aware that the date component built into the trigger definition is immutable once created. Only the creating statement itself (and the trigger function) are "dynamic".

Related:

- [Trigger function taking column names as parameters to modify the row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127787/trigger-function-taking-column-names-as-parameters-to-modify-the-row/127826#127826)

***But*** that seems like **needless complication**. No need to pass the name of the table for which the trigger is called. [Some special variables are available automatically in plpgsql trigger functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html). Among others: `TG_TABLE_SCHEMA` and `TG_TABLE_NAME`. So use dynamic SQL in the trigger function, but the trigger itself can be simple and static:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_insert_data_func() 
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$func$ 
BEGIN  
   EXECUTE format(
   $x$INSERT INTO tb_moldsummary AS t
      SELECT $1.machine                               
           , $1.model
           , split_part($1.lot, '_', 1)
           , right($1.lot, position('_' IN lot) * -1)    
           , COUNT(*)  -- never null in this query
           , $1.datetimestamp
      FROM   %I.%I     -- !!
      WHERE  lot = $1.lot
      AND    machine = $1.machine
      GROUP  BY machine, model, lot
      ON     CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT tb_summary_unique  -- constraint has same name?
      DO     UPDATE
      SET    machine = $1.machine                     
           , totalshots = t.totalshots + 1
           , datetimestamp = $1.datetimestamp
   $x$, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME   -- !!
   )
   USING NEW;                                            
   RETURN NEW; 
END
$func$  
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And no parameters in the trigger itself.

Comment: I passed the parameter containing tablename on trigger function, but your answer is much better. No need to pass the paramater, much better to use the **TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME**. Thanks Erwin. Its such a big help.